# HTML/JS site templates?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm a PHP programmer that was just hired to write an interactive ipad app whose requirements are basically that it be a website. So I started setting up to develop a website when I found out that my employer's server has been lobotomized: no dynamic languages, the only things I'm allowed to code with are HTML and JavaScript.

AJAX and jQuery are still in, but as far as I can tell they won't have a server-side language to back them up. If I have an urgent and compelling reason to have an active language, I might be able to convince the senior web guy to give me an exception, but I don't think my project qualifies as urgent or compelling by about two orders of magnitude.

My question then, is what sort of labor-saving devices are out there for HTML/JS only sites? I would have liked to use something like Drupal. Would I be better off writing the whole thing in XCode?

The site will display information regarding a number of historical artifacts in the possession of the library that is my employer.

Comment: The need to build a website in 2014 constitutes an urgent and compelling reason to have a proper server. For 4 bucks a month you can have decent shared hosting, for crying out loud. That said, your question is too broad for SO. Best of luck.

Comment: *javascript. AJAX and Jquery* - All JavaScript FYI - what kind of site is this where no back end data is needed?

Comment: I am displaying information on physical objects. Each content page can have its own static HTML file and those files loaded into a template. The primary purpose of the site is to put it on an ipad and let users navigate around on it while staring at the physical objects themselves. As a secondary purpose, users will be able to learn about the library special collection while not actually in the archives room.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would help if you were more specific about your needs (the kinds of things you do in PHP that you don't know how to do with just HTML/JS), but I think I know what you're getting at.

If the site isn't too complicated, a good client-side templating engine is probably what you're looking for. Handlebars.js is a popular choice, but there are tons to choose from. I prefer to use client-jade, but it doesn't matter much. The idea is to define a template (e.g. for displaying one historical artifact), then iterate over an array of data that describes all the artifacts in the library, rendering each element of the array into some pretty-looking DOM with your template.

If you need something more sophisticated than that, you might want a client-side MVC framework like Backbone.js (lightweight, easier to learn, less opinionated) or Angular.js (heavier, harder to learn, very opinionated).

If the labor you're trying to save yourself from doing is styling work, you might want to check out twitter bootstrap (or similar frameworks like foundation). Bootstrap makes it easy to create good-looking navbars, make column-based layouts, and ensure that your site looks good across different browsers and devices.

Comment: Thank you. I typically write PHP/MySQL applications and abstract away almost the entire HTML layer by using tools like Drupal, but I can't do that here. I will definitely check out bootstrap and client-jade. A client-side model-view-controller framework sounds like it might be exactly what I need.